# how to find subsets of a set in matlab?

Tags: matlab

I have a set of numbers with 28 members. For example:

```
A=1:28;
```

I want to divided the set to 4 parts(each parts includes 7 numbers). How can I find all subsets? I prefer to save subsets in 4 matrixes to calculate sum of each subset and other math operations.

Comment: So: you want all possible partitions into subsets of 7 elements each, right? The number of such partitions seems to be about `nchoosek(28,7) * nchoosek(21,7) * nchoosek(14,7)`, which is probably more than your computer memory can hold

Answer (score -1):

On the implementation, please have a look at:
http://matlabtricks.com/post-9/get-all-subsets-having-a-given-length
, where the author proposed two ways for implementation.

-- Naive way: Enumeration all the subsets of a set except the empty set, which can be realized by the trick of binary decomposition ( see http://matlabtricks.com/post-7/select-all-subsets-of-a-set).  Counting the size of each subsets and select ones with a fixed size.

-- A non-trivial algorithm: It requires an initial subset with a fixed size. With this set, one can generate other similar subsets with same size by permutations.

Tell me if you have any further questions.

Cheers